# How to upload image file to aws s3 from android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I write wrong directory of image file,
the error is made like this

02-28 20:30:08.451 16381-17624/app.s3amazon E/UploadTask: Failed to upload: 217 due to Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/pleaseee.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

And if I write right directory, the error is like this

02-28 20:28:52.331 21752-15679/app.s3amazon E/UploadPartTask: Encountered error uploading part The specified file doesn't exist

the code is

```
File fileToUpload = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera/pleaseee.jpg");
File fileToDownload = new File("");
AmazonS3 s3;
TransferUtility transferUtility;
```

and upload code is

```
public void setFileToUpload(View view){
            TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload("sangmin", "please.jpg", fileToUpload);

    transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
}
```

I cannot understand the error 
'The specified file doesn't exist'

Is that mean is about cannot find any image file in directory that I wrote?

Comment: Do you have the permissions for accessing storage on your app?